How to take column dynamically in foreignKey in Sequelize
I have two separate tables CourseOffer and CourseAddon where CourseAddon has foreignKey courseOfferId in CourseAddon table.
Now I wish to add a new column in my CourseOffer table named alternateCourseOfferId which in itself is linked to another CourseOffer.
Table "public.CourseOffer"
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('"CourseOffer_id_seq"'::regclass)
 title          | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 description    | text                     |           |          | 
 courseId       | integer                  |           | not null | 
 fee            | numeric(10,2)            |           | not null | 
 discountedFee  | numeric(10,2)            |           |          | 
 email          | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 phone          | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 expiryAt       | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 durationInDays | integer                  |           |          | 
 offerExpiryAt  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 offerStartedAt | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 admin_user_id  | integer                  |           |          | 
 hidden         | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 position       | integer                  |           |          | 
 createdAt      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 updatedAt      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 actualCourseId | integer                  |           |          | 
 accepted       | boolean                  |           |          | false
 hasShipment    | boolean                  |           |          | false
 allowCoupon    | boolean                  |           |          | false
 allowAddon     | boolean                  |           |          | false


Table "public.CourseAddon"
       Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('"CourseAddon_id_seq"'::regclass)
 courseId           | integer                     |           |          | 
 addonCourseId      | integer                     |           |          | 
 createdAt          | timestamp without time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 updatedAt          | timestamp without time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 courseOfferId      | integer                     |           |          | 
 addonCourseOfferId | integer                     |           |          | 
 seqId              | integer                     |           |          | 



I am having a Sequelize relation in CourseOffer which finds all associated CourseAddon.
CourseOffer.Addons = CourseOffer.hasMany(CourseAddon, {
    foreignKey: 'courseOfferId',
    scope: (findOptions) => ({
      courseOfferId: {$ne: null},
      $and: Model.literal('"CourseAddon"."courseId" = (SELECT "courseId" from "CourseOffer" where "CourseOffer"."id" = "courseOfferId")'),
    }),
    as: 'addons',
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
  });

I wish that if alternateCourseOfferId exists in a CourseOffer, it should look via the value of alternateCourseOfferId in place of id as foreignKey.
How to modify the Sequelize query to achieve these results?
I am expecting if a CourseOffer has alternateCourseOfferId, it should search via alternateCourseOfferId in place of id over CourseAddon table.
